# Mutiplying dataframe by -1 loses data

Tags: python, pandas, multiplication

I have an issue and I have no idea what is causing it.. I have a very very simply dataframe which looks like the following;

```
            A   B
01/01/2022 -34 -102.34
02/01/2022 -4  -89.23
03/01/2022 -78 -43.2
.
.
.
31/12/2022 -32 -34.21
```

I simply need to convert this dataframe to positive numbers.
When I do this with a simple;

```
df = df * -1
```

A column multiples but the B column loses its' data to the following;

```
            A   B
01/01/2022 34 
02/01/2022 4  
03/01/2022 78 
.
.
.
31/12/2022 32
```

I assume this is something to do with interger vs float64 but just can't crack it.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What is `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: A float64
B object
dtype: object

I've no idea why it for some reason has been turned into an object..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely have strings in your data, multiplying a string by an integer less than 1 converts to empty string:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,1,2], 'B': [0,'1',2]})
df*-1
```

output:

```
   A   B
0  0   0
1 -1    
2 -2  -2
```

Workaround: convert [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')*-1

# or
# df.astype(float)*-1
```

output:

```
   A  B
0  0  0
1 -1 -1
2 -2 -2
```